# Replicate normal mode function in visual mode

Tags: visual-mode, functions

I had the following mapping to go to the 1st non blank character of a line

> ```
> nnoremap M ^
> ```

I then decided that if I was already at the 1st non blank character I wanted M to take me to the absolute 1st character of the line.
I was able to hack together the following vimscript function to do this.

> ```
> func Mbehaviour()
>     let origPos = getcurpos()
>     normal! ^
>     let newPos = getcurpos()
>     call setpos('.', origPos)
>     if newPos == origPos
>         execute "normal! \<Home>"
>     else
>         normal! ^
>     endif
> endfun
> ```
>
> & then map this to M with
>
> ```
> nnoremap M :call Mbehaviour()<CR>
> ```

My question is how can I get the same thing to work in visual mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/plugin/homeLikeVC%2B%2B.vim), I have a single (old) function that can be used from all three modes.

```
inoremap <silent> <Home> <c-o>@=<SID>HomeLikeVCpp()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <Home> @=<SID>HomeLikeVCpp()<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <Home> @=<SID>HomeLikeVCpp()<cr>

function! s:HomeLikeVCpp()
  let ll = strpart(getline('.'), -1, col('.'))
  if ll =~ '^\s\+$' | return '0'
  else              | return '^'
  endif
endfunction
```

I guess it could be rewritten as a `:map-<expr>` now.

Years later, I'm wondering why I was bothering to test a substring against a regex, while testing the current column is more than enough -- unless we really want to start with the first non blank character.

```
xnoremap <expr> <home> col('.') == 1 ? '^' : '0'
nnoremap <expr> <home> col('.') == 1 ? '^' : '0'
inoremap <expr> µ col('.') == 1 ? '<c-o>^' : '<c-o>0'
```

Anyway, don't fight with `:normal`. I found best to avoid this command from functions whenever I can. Keep it simple.